# How do i output an SQL Error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, handle

I've declared an handler which will handle SQLEXCEPTION, in the clean up code i had it do `SELECT 'My Handle';`, i ran a script that fails because of a primary key violation and it worked cause i got my output.

the problem with `DECLARE ... HANDLE FOR SQLEXCEPTION` is that when there is an error it will run though it's doesn't say what error triggered it, so i want to output the error

How do i output the SQL Error using a MySQL Query, i don't care if i can only output the error code/id i just need something to output giving me an indication on what the error is so i can fix the problem

EDIT: in case if it's not obvious, this code is in an SQL Procedure

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the [DECLARE HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) documentation on this functionality. You could handle the errors MySQL returns to your application and print or log them that way.

Comment: the application is a automated job on the server which runs the stored procedure i want to but the handler in, while i can find plenty of documentation on outputting the SQL Error in C or PHP the problem is that i'm using none of them and not to mention that i was to log the Error in a table so that during the weekend if it fails i can check out what the original error was in case if the error changes over multiple fails (has happened, spent a whole day only to figure that out)

Comment: Also, i should note, the link you provided i ready read well, the only example that comes close to handling an error that stops queries (as the other examples deals with warnings) is the first one and it's a horrible example as it effectively ignores the error without any indication of an error and continues, the example is supposed to demonstrate how `CONTINUE` executes it's clean up code and then continues with the original query but as an example of the basics, it's inline with W3Schools saying to use direct input from a HTML Form into a Query with no sanitation of the data

Answer (score 0):

I actually haven't used any handles, but i think you can make your code into a stored procedure and then run the stored procedure!! You might find MySQL accepts what you are trying to do then.